# Dreamweaver keeps pulling external CSS file together with local CSS on local server

Tags: javascript, php, css, server, dreamweaver

Dreamweaver CS5, XAMPP Server, PHP files

This happened to me before with the above version, when my various websites inside *htdocs* folder would pull a particular website's CSS file. When checked as 'Live View' I could locate all the external .css and .js files, but there was no way of finding out the location of these files and HOW it was pulled as dependent files.

This all happened, probably by accident, when I was setting up the 'Manage Sites' and its Server so the site could be viewed on localhost.

1- Make sure, when you set up your 'Local Site Folder' address, do NOT leave your path on htdocs, but choose the website folder you are working on.

2- Even if by accident you have left your path as 'htdocs' once, what it does is create a copy of your website inside htdocs.  Meaning, while you still work with files inside your website folder, it pulls .css and .js files from htdocs level as well.  If you left your path as XAMPP, it will create those copied website folders on XAMPP level, and will keep pulling those older versions together with your updated files and drive you bonkers.

Not sure if I am clear about this problem with the above Dreamweaver version, but it cost me a delayed start on a customer's website.  I lost 3 days plus an amount of frustration and a gazillion testings. Unfortunately, I had not kept notes on how I resolved it before.  I couldn't find anywhere on the internet a similar post.

Delete those re-created folders on the server level above all the other website folders inside your htdocs folder.

Comment: Let us look into your files :)

Comment: @aimme do you mean at htdocs level?

Comment: What does `pull external css` even mean? Nothing will get put into a page that isn't defined within the page source sent to browser, or scripts contained within

Comment: @charlietfl I couldn't fit my answer in here so I answered my own question also trying to create a mental picture.  Please advice if I can use another approach in describing.  Thank you  :)

Comment: forget live preview temporarily...when you open a page in browser you can see the path to all css resources. Even if directories were copied the original directories wouldn't be changed. Sounds more like you edited the wrong files or have bad paths in the `<link>` tags

Comment: Can you show an example please on how you would view your css path in the browser?   I checked the <link> paths inside my .php/html header many times.  They were correct.  I kept deleting and attaching back the local css, but that would not change anything in picking up the .css on htdocs level together with the local .css.

Comment: @ charlietfl as an example, I will recommend you put an arbitrary css folder inside your htdocs folder, with an outdated .css file, or let's say, a different .css file you used for another website.  Do not change anything in your current website and run the preview on your localhost.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say, you have a folder for each website inside htdocs.  Each website has its own unique .css files:
htdocs/
Website1 folder.
Website2 folder.
Website3 folder.

When you work on Website3 folder and run a 'Preview' on your localhost, your Website3 will pick up your Website1 menu design and .css values.  You will get a mishmash of design.

When setting up your Website1 local server, you made a mistake in putting your path as '.../htdocs/' instead of '.../htdocs/Website1'.  So it creates a copy of all your folders inside 'htdocs' that affects all the other websites:  Website1, Website2 and Website3.    I think this is Dreamweaver CS5 'bug' while trying to simplify things, it is re-creating files in the background without you being aware of.